I am facing issue in ads_management Permission After App Review
I'm encountering issues with obtaining ads_management permission for my app after a recent app review. Before in previos app reviews i did not require this permission, but now i want this permissionbut could not find in permissions. Additionally, when attempting to request permissions and features through the developer dashboard, I'm redirected to use cases that do not address my specific needs.
Details:
App Type: ** Business App **
App Mode: ** Live **
Issue Description:
Problem: Unable to obtain ads_management permission.
Observation: Clicking on "Request Permissions and Features" redirects me to unrelated use cases.
Could someone from the community please guide me on how to properly request and obtain ads_management, catalog_management, and commerce_account_manage_orders permissions post-app review?
Any insights or steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I tried number of times even i go into the business manager and have created systrem user but could not get these permissions.
